# See when a file last changed on http server

Tags: linux, shell, curl, wget, last-modified

I'm interested in how I can see when a file on a server was last updated.

I've tested `curl -s -v -X HEAD http://example.com/file.txt  2>&1 | grep '^< Last-Modified:'`
but not all servers leaves a last-modified result.

using `curl` or `wget` to download the file changes the last modified date.

is there anyway to get around this?
..

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is not a file oriented protocol and therefore you're left with what the HTTP server provides. In fact, the file you're trying to reach might not be an actual file at all.

You might want to use protocols such as FTP or SFTP instead, or take advantage of directory listing (if provided by the server).

Comment: that would be possible only if the file I wanted to check was on a SFTP server, but I want to be able to check any file, on any server. if necessary I'll download the file before checking..

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. Also, you're not downloading a file. You're downloading some data that *may* be interpreted as a file based on the HTTP response headers.